# If solution is run immediately after rebuilding, files that are copied to output directory are deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Issue: If solution is run immediately after rebuilding, files that are copied to output directory are deleted.

Visual Studio version: Community 2013 Version 12.040629.00 Update 5

Running on Windows 10

My solution is structured like this:

```
MySolution.Services (library project)

MySolution.Main (startup project - WPF application)
```

In the services project, there are some files that are marked "Copy to output directory = Copy Always".  When I build I am able to see the files being output to the correct directory.
 None of my projects have build events.
 All of my projects output to "..\Builds".

The following sequence works correctly (files are not deleted):

Make a random change to a .cs file

Click Start Debugging

The following sequence causes the files in the output directory to be deleted:

Click Build -> Rebuild Solution

Click Start Debugging

Files in output directory are deleted immediately.

I am able to reproduce this issue at will.
 I have a breakpoint in Application_Startup.  I can see the files are deleted before any of my code runs (BTW I have no code in my application that deletes these files under any condition.):

I have posted this same question on the Visual Studio Forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99f36ff7-2de6-4da5-955c-b5b59c6b6f32/if-solution-is-run-immediately-after-rebuilding-files-that-are-copied-to-output-directory-are?forum=visualstudiogeneral).
My solution has seven projects and probably several hundred files.  Before I spend a day adding files one by one and clicking "Build" I am hoping that someone can guide me to a more productive troubleshooting path.  Also, I am very leery about exporting and importing VS settings as I have corrupted my VS installation in the past and I really do not want to risk doing that again.  I do not want to second guess the MS technician who is trying to help me - I want to get second opinions before doing something I might regret.

Comment: Have exactly the same problem. Can reproduce that on every PC with my project. After Rebuild I have files in output folder and after running from VS my files dissapear. At this point I can run project correctly only from output folder manually so I can't debug. Please share your solution if you fixed it.

Comment: This appears to be a VS bug.  The only workaround I know is to make a random change to a cs file before debugging (do not rebuild before debugging).

Answer (score 2):

This could happen when the project is composed of several dlls, and the files that are being copied to the output directory are part of one of the dependant dlls.

If the dependency is not direct to the final, executable, project, but is second level (final project depends on dll x, which depends on dll y, which has the content to be copied) then, although VS has copied the files to the output directory of the final executable during the build, it determines at startup of the debugger that they shouldn't really be there and removes them.

The solution is to make the indirect dependency a direct dependency of the final executable.

Comment: "If the dependency is not direct to the final, executable, project.." Thank you for the answer but this is not the scenario in the question.

Comment: This did solve the issue for me. I had Project A (a console application) reference Project B (a DLL), which referenced Project C (another DLL). Project C had resources (text files) that were set to be copied if newer to the build directory. I now set Project A to reference Project C directly and this solved the disappearing resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the process of deleted files when setting:

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity:`
**Diagnostics**

I have the same issue. And when building my Project is see in the output-dir:

```
Removed Item(s): 
1>    Reference=
1>        Missing.Box
1>                HintPath=..\lib\Missing.Box.dll
1>                SpecificVersion=False
...
```

Full article i found that:
https://oz-code.com/blog/visual-studio-keeps-rebuilding-projects-no-good-reason/

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a work around solution you could try one of the solutions described in 'how to prevent content files to be removed during a build' - neither have any votes, but its worth a try. [How to prevent content files to be removed during incremental build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548635/how-to-prevent-content-files-to-be-removed-during-incremental-build)