# How to prevent content files to be removed during incremental build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 solution with 3 projects:

My top-level application is `MyApp` which has a project reference on `ClassLibrary2` which in turn has a project reference on `ClassLibrary1`:

```
MyApp -> ClassLibrary2 -> ClassLibrary1
```

The `ClassLibrary1` has a data file, `data.bin`, that is required for its normal execution. It is expected that this data file will be found in a `Resources/` sub-folder relative to where the `ClassLibrary1` assembly is when the application is executed. The structure of the `ClassLibrary1` is similar to:

```
ClassLibrary1.csproj
    Resources/
        data.bin
    MyClassBehaviorDrivenByData.cs
    ...
```

The `data.bin` file has its `Build Action` property set to `Content` (I have also tried with `None`) and its `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy If Newer`.

If I do a full solution Rebuild, the `data.bin` file finds its way to the output directory of `MyApp`, as expected. However, if I do some changes in the `MyApp` project and build the solution, the `data.bin` file is **deleted** from the output directory of `MyApp` (note: the Output window shows that only `MyApp` is built since only the code of `MyApp` was changed).

Workarounds:

1. I could use post-build steps in `MyApp` to forcefully copy the data file to the output directory each time `MyApp` builds. However, this goes against the principle that the developer "owning" `ClassLibrary1` should not have to worry about modifying post-build scripts in consuming projects if he adds a new data file, modify existing ones or move them elsewhere.
2. I could directly add a reference to `ClassLibrary1` from `MyApp`. However, this violates the desire to hide away the `ClassLibrary1` functionality/API under the `ClassLibrary2` API (i.e., I don't want `ClassLibrary1` API to leak into `MyApp`).

My questions are: what causes the `data.bin` file to be deleted from `MyApp`'s output directory during incremental builds of `MyApp` and is there a way to prevent this to happen without using one of the 2 workarounds listed above?

Comment: In your output window, how many projects did it build? Whether the ClassLibrary1 and 2 also builds successfully? Before you build the MyApp, if you build the classlibrary projects firstly, does it have this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai ClassLibrary1, ClassLibrary2 as well as MyApp all build successfully when I **Rebuild** the whole Solution (and data.bin appears somewhere under the MyApp output directory). However, once everything is built and I hack away at MyApp and then **Build** the solution, only MyApp shows up in the Output window (which is what I would expect given that I am only editing the code of MyApp). Obviously, I could rebuild the solution each time I modify the code in MyApp, but this is a large solution and doing a full rebuild is unpractical. I edited the question to clarify a bit more this point.

Comment: Do you try my workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that that file is deleted in Incremental Clean task, that is used to make sure the files are newest (but it just delete files for your scenario). 
To deal with this issue, you can add a new target to copy necessary files to the target folder.

For example(edit csproj file, add this code to the end (before ):

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <resourceFiles Include="..\ClassLibrary1\Resources\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CopyFiles">
 </Target>
 <Target Name="CopyFiles" Inputs="@(resourceFiles)"
        Outputs="@(resourceFiles->'bin\$(Configuration)\Resources\%(filename)%(extension)')">
    <Message Text="after Copy files" Importance="high"/>
    <Copy
           SourceFiles="@(resourceFiles)"
           DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Resources"
        />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution is different than my "workaround" #1 but it seems to come with the same caveat. That is, it goes against the principle that the developer "owning" ClassLibrary1 should not have to worry about modifying msbuild .csproj file in consuming projects if he adds a new data file (folder in this case), modify existing ones or move them elsewhere. However, this makes me think that I might be able to use msbuild in ClassLibrary2 to dynamically add content file. I haven't had the chance to try your solution or what I just described yet.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried this workaround in the project file for ClassLibrary1, which is where I would prefer it to be for the reason Fredpo  mentioned, but as expected it does not get copied to either ClassLibrary2 or MyApp. Also, it is not removed when doing a Clean on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

My workaround, although I am not very fond of it, is including the file data.bin in the ClassLibrary2 probject and setting "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". I also set the same property for data.bin in ClassLibrary1 to "Do not copy".

Comment: When adding data.bin to ClassLibrary2 I used "Add as Link", to at least avoid keeping the file in two places.